# Spaces are causing issues - Automate merging PDF with batch file

Tags: pdf, toolkit

Goal: We save out a couple hundred PDF's everyday into a folder. Every night I want a batch file to run that will merge all of these alphabetically into one PDF and move it into another folder.

So far I am using pdftoolkit and a batch file to perform the merge. It works perfectly... unless there are spaces. I would really like to make it foolproof so I don't have to tell everyone "don't save with spaces". Below is the .bat file text...

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F %%A IN ('dir /B /ON *.pdf') DO (set command=!command! "%%A")
pdftk.exe %command% cat output "%~dp1%DATE:~6,4%%DATE:~3,2%%DATE:~0,2%_Title_Here.pdf"
```

The **/b /on** do a good job of making them alphabetized, however if any PDF contains a space in the title, it thinks they are separate files and causes the batch to fail. Any ideas how to "space-proof" this batch?

Note: I am VERY new to coding and this is my first post on here. Please keep that in mind when giving solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Adding a FOR option to take all tokens in a line seems to do the trick. See below. Works great!

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "tokens=* delims= " %%A IN ('dir /B /ON *.pdf') DO (set command=!command! "%%A")
pdftk.exe %command% cat output "%~dp1%DATE:~6,4%%DATE:~3,2%%DATE:~0,2%_Title_Here.pdf"
```